# Does CiviRules extension work on 4.6.x

Tags: civirules

Title says it all really. Just trying to verify if there are known breakages, or if we just need to update the [Extension info page](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules)

Answer (score 3):

We're using it on 4.6.x sites too and are in the process of adding extra things such as the ability to allocate campaigns. If theres anything in particular you'd like to do but cant maybe drop into a wiki or on the issues list in github.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed CiviRules on 4.6.8 without incident and have built some Rules to cover situation of when a contact gains a Membership then add them to a Group. This all seems to work. There are Conditions I need which don't exist but fundamentally I am not seeing anything broken wrt the Extension.

Comment: CiviRules aims to share an engine, it was never our ambition to create all required conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we are using CiviRules on 4.6.x without incident thus far (see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4873/105 for an example of how). It's very helpful. It didn't have exactly the condition/action combo we needed, but using it in conjunction with other features of core CiviCRM, we made it work for us.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't seem to work with any of the event triggers (create,change,delete) across versions 4.6.x and 4.7.x

This error message comes up.

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer

Have you had any issues with the event triggers petednz?

Comment: It would help if you make your comments or ask your questions in one place? So we can help you? (duplicates at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12715/civirule-error-on-create-event and https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/90

Comment: Hi Erik,  1 question was asking about a function that didn't work. I found 2 questions asking about issues with civirules with 4.6.x and 4.7.x and I answered them with the current issue I am having as I have cross tested on both versions. So other people who are installing civirules who are after similar functionality are aware. I have also created an issue log on the official github repo so the ext creators are aware of the issue. I didn't really see this as duplicating as github is a separate platform, and I am answering questions on stockexchange. I'm sorry if its come across like that.