# CiviRule Error on create Event

Tags: civievent, civirules

The error message I am receiving is:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer

I have tested this on a clean install of CiviCRM 4.6.18 with only CiviRules installed and still get this error. It occurs on any Event Trigger (create,change,delete).

and spits out this backtrace error:

```
#0 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(360): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(415): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer")
#2 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1251): CRM_Utils_Type::validate(NULL, "Integer")
#3 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1168): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("INSERT INTO `civirule_rule_log` (`rule_id`, `contact_id`, `log_date`) VALUES ...", (Array:2), TRUE)
#4 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/org.civicoop.civirules-master/CRM/Civirules/Engine.php(285): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("INSERT INTO `civirule_rule_log` (`rule_id`, `contact_id`, `log_date`) VALUES ...", (Array:2))
#5 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/org.civicoop.civirules-master/CRM/Civirules/Engine.php(30): CRM_Civirules_Engine::logRule(Object(CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_Post))
#6 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/org.civicoop.civirules-master/CRM/Civirules/Trigger/Post.php(81): CRM_Civirules_Engine::triggerRule(Object(CRM_Civirules_Trigger_Post), Object(CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_Post))
#7 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/org.civicoop.civirules-master/CRM/Civirules/Trigger/Post.php(66): CRM_Civirules_Trigger_Post->triggerTrigger("create", "Event", 12, Object(CRM_Event_DAO_Event))
#8 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/org.civicoop.civirules-master/civirules.php(137): CRM_Civirules_Trigger_Post::post("create", "Event", 12, Object(CRM_Event_DAO_Event))
#9 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(213): civirules_civicrm_post("create", "Event", 12, Object(CRM_Event_DAO_Event))
#10 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php(87): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:33), "civicrm_post", 4, "create", "Event", 12, Object(CRM_Event_DAO_Event), NULL, NULL)
#11 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(304): CRM_Utils_Hook_DrupalBase->invoke(4, "create", "Event", 12, Object(CRM_Event_DAO_Event), NULL, NULL, "civicrm_post")
#12 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php(110): CRM_Utils_Hook::post("create", "Event", 12, Object(CRM_Event_DAO_Event))
#13 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php(141): CRM_Event_BAO_Event::add((Array:28))
#14 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/EventInfo.php(307): CRM_Event_BAO_Event::create((Array:28))
#15 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(345): CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_EventInfo->postProcess()
#16 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(166): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#17 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(133): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_EventInfo), "upload")
#18 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_EventInfo), "upload")
#19 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_EventInfo), "upload")
#20 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
#21 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(115): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#22 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(286): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_EventInfo", "New Event", NULL)
#23 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#24 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#25 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#26 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "add")
#27 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#28 /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#29 {main}
```

I would really like some help debugging this error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are discussing this problem at the moment on GitHub too? https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/90

It looks like you are passing a NULL value as a parameter to a function in the civirules logging. You could try to add a check for a NULL value in CRM/Civirules/Engine.php. Does this help? And great if you can fix this error in a PR on GitHub.

Comment: Indeed follow the discussion on github

Comment: Thanks Erik & Jaap I mainly posted this here to see if anyone else is experiencing these issues and if so what solution did they come up with. I am not coder but have troubleshoot issues in the past and fixed modules with help. I will continue discussions within github and once a solution is present I will Answer it here also for others searching with similar issues.